# What did the Cossack utter towards the two men in "The Duellists"?

Tags: dialogue, translation, the-duellists

There is a point in [*The Duellists*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075968/) where in Russia, they are about to duel each other with pistols. They are interrupted by a Cossack who spews some words at them. What did he say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewatched this movie yesterday, and, as a matter of fact, the Cossack says:

In Russian:

> — Vy golodnye? (Вы голодные?) 
> — Myasa khoteetye? (Мяса хотите?) 
> *(laughs and spits something)* 
> — Vy golodnye? (Вы голодные?)

Translated to English:

> — Are you hungry? 
> — Do you want some meat? 
> *(laughs and spits something)* 
> — Are you hungry?

Comment: Wait, so which one is right?

Comment: Hmm, I just posted what I've heard. I'm not sure where @dickturpin got his answer, but it doesn't seem to match.

Answer (score 1):

"You two will die out in this cold. Come with me and we will eat in the warmth."

Comment: Someone provided a completely different answer. Where did your source come from?